# ClickOnce Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: iis-7, vsto, clickonce, mime-types, http-status-code-403

A customer gets a 403 error when trying to install our VSTO ClickOnce application. We are hosted on GoDaddy IIS7.

"Downloading (one of our files ending in .deploy) did not succeed. System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error (403): Forbidden."

FWIW I've made sure all files needed for the installation are present in the remote directory. The publish from Visual Studio succeeds without any errors.

The installer is hosted on GoDaddy, and it has [all the correct ClickOnce MIME types](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3821/what-mime-types-does-my-windows-hosting-account-support-by-default) set. We didn't modify any of these.

BTW, could not find the ClickOnce error log! Searching online reveals that the log [is located in Temporary Internet Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404265.aspx) by default, but it was not there. We don't have our own custom log file location set, and we'd prefer not to set up a custom location for the customer's log if we can just grab the default one instead. It doesn't sound as though the log file provides any additional information beyond the stack trace revealed by the "Details" button in the error dialog, anyway.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? i'm having the same problem with my VSTO app...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is no read access to this file for your customers.

Try to download the file directly.

Comment: A good thought, but I can download the .deploy file just fine manually.

Comment: It's unlikely but do you have maybe some .htaccess restrictions?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention we are on IIS7. Working with their support to try adding support for the .vsto MIME type via a web.config file. Although you'd think if it were MIME we wouldn't even get as far as downloading the .vsto file.